# VB.Net Caching SQL Server data using DataTables and checksum

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, join, caching

## Caching SQL Server data using DataTables and checksum

I'm rebuilding a Winforms application in VB.Net with a SQL Server database at the back end. I'm trying to limit retrieving data from SQL Server by implementing caching in DataTables. To detect changes in the the SQL Server table data I use the T-SQL command: `CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))` to calculate the table data checksum and record this checksum locally. When a next data retrieve takes place, the current checksum is compared to the locally recorded checksum and the DataTable is again filled only when the checksum has changed and then also the new checksum is recorded.
In this approach I maintain 4 DataTables and I have to perform a kind of `JOIN` filling in specific fields in the 1th DataTable from the 3 other DataTables.
I've looked into LINQ to implement this but one of my requirements is to show the data in a DataGridView which requires the CopyToDataTable for the LINQ query which is unacceptable slow processing some 17000 records.
My **main question** is: am I on the right track or am I missing something.
My Class now consists of:

```
...
    Public Sub New(ConnectionString As String)
        Dim ChkRow As DataRow
        Dim SQLDataQuery As String = ""
        Dim SQLCheckQuery As String = ""
        DbConnectionString = ConnectionString
        TblCheckRetrieve.Columns.Add("Table", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        TblCheckRetrieve.Columns.Add("DataQuery", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        TblCheckRetrieve.Columns.Add("CheckQuery", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        TblCheckRetrieve.Columns.Add("Checksum", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
        TblCheckRetrieve.AcceptChanges()

        ' fill tables
        SQLDataQuery = "SELECT * FROM ViewConnectionsOnly ORDER BY BuildingID, Room, Outlet;"
        SQLCheckQuery = "DECLARE @Chksum AS int; SELECT @Chksum = CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) FROM Connections" &
            "With (NOLOCK); IF @Chksum IS NULL SELECT 0; ELSE SELECT @Chksum;"
        Using DbCon As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DbConnectionString),
                DbAdapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(SQLDataQuery, DbCon),
                DbCommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQLCheckQuery, DbCon)
            DbCon.Open()
            ChkRow = TblCheckRetrieve.NewRow ' TblCheckRetrieve is a local DataTable that holds the info on tables and there queries and the checksum
            ChkRow.Item("Table") = "Connections"
            ChkRow.Item("DataQuery") = SQLDataQuery
            ChkRow.Item("CheckQuery") = SQLCheckQuery
            ChkRow.Item("Checksum") = DbCommand.ExecuteScalar ' get checksum
            TblCheckRetrieve.Rows.Add(ChkRow)
            DbAdapter.Fill(TblConnections)
        End Using
...
```

Now, when data is requested calling `RetrieveData()` the checksum is checked and when the checksum is changed the table data is cleared and filled and the checksum is recorded again in routine `ChecksumChanged` and the tables are joined in `JoinTables()`.

```
   Private Sub RetrieveData()
        ' a new request to retrieve data
        Dim Rebuild As Boolean = False
        For Each RRow As DataRow In TblCheckRetrieve.Rows
            If ChecksumChanged(RRow.Item("Table")) Then
                Rebuild = True
            End If
        Next
        If Rebuild Then ' checksum changed for one or more tables
            JoinTables()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function ChecksumChanged(ByVal Tablename As String) As Boolean
        Dim SelectCriteria As String = "Table = '" & Tablename & "'"
        Dim CheckRow As DataRow = TblCheckRetrieve.Select(SelectCriteria)(0)
        Dim NewChecksum As Decimal = 0
        Using DbCon As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DbConnectionString),
            DbAdapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(CheckRow.Item("DataQuery"), DbCon),
            DbCommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(CheckRow.Item("CheckQuery"), DbCon)
            DbCon.Open()
            NewChecksum = DbCommand.ExecuteScalar
            If NewChecksum <> CheckRow.Item("Checksum") Then
                CheckRow.Item("Checksum") = NewChecksum
                Select Case Tablename
                    Case "Connections"
                        TblConnections.Clear()
                        DbAdapter.Fill(TblConnections)
                    Case "Buildings"
                        TblBuildings.Clear()
                        DbAdapter.Fill(TblBuildings)
                    Case "Switches"
                        TblSwitches.Clear()
                        DbAdapter.Fill(TblSwitches)
                    Case "VLANs"
                        TblVLANs.Clear()
                        DbAdapter.Fill(TblVLANs)
                End Select
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using

    End Function

    Private Sub JoinTables()
        ' Join (or rather fill in) the data from tables Building, Switch and VLAN in table Connections
        For Each Arow As DataRow In TblConnections.Rows
            Arow.Item("Building") = Arow.Item("BuildingID") & "-" & TblBuildings.Select("BuildingID=" & Arow.Item("BuildingID"))(0).Item("Building")
            Arow.Item("Switch") = TblSwitches.Select("SwitchID=" & Arow.Item("SwitchID"))(0).Item("Switch")
            Arow.Item("VLAN") = TblVLANs.Select("VLANID=" & Arow.Item("VLANID"))(0).Item("VLAN")
        Next
        ConnectionsRowCount = TblConnections.Rows.Count
    End Sub
```

Comment: If your overall goal is to speed things up I'd first take a look at why you are serving up 17000+ records? Unless you're generating some kind graph and those records are data series there is no human on earth that is going to be able to process 17000 rows of data

Comment: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: `... FROM Connections" & "With (NOLOCK); ...` is very likely to error too.

Comment: While I agree that 17000 rows is a lot of info to be displaying on a datagridview, the are a couple strategies you could employ to lessen the visible effects of data access for caching. 1) You could implement background workers to do the data retrieval 2) You could implement a paging strategy (Get 1000 record blocks at a time for example) 3) a combo of both these techniques.  P.S.  in all my years experience, don't think I can remember ever using NOLOCK

Comment: @frosto: I understand implementing paging would limit the data to be retrieved. But, for the sake of argument lets say I do need all 17000 records because the DataGridView displaying the data is on a form with filters to allow the users to quickly select all records for a specific building and then change filtering to select all connections on a specific switch or some other criteria. The question remains: does implementing a cache strategy as set out work?

Comment: @Hursey: using NOLOCK would take all data, even uncommited data, into consideration which serves my purpose

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question: I've ended up implementing [virtual mode with just-in-time data loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/virtual-mode-with-just-in-time-data-loading-in-the-datagrid) which uses paging and caching data from a SQL Server database, with a couple of changes to Class DataRetriever:

- implemented a USING construct to replace using SqlConnection as parameter
- using a Stored Procedure to retrieve pages of data from the table
- using a timestamp to perform checksum calculation after a page is more than 2 mins old and when the checksum is changed, refresh the cached data

and to Class Cache:

- add the aforementioned Timestamp to Structure DataPage